# Get total PDF pages using iTextSharp and display it to textBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

How do I get total PDF pages display in listbox or datagridview then display total number pages in the textbox?

This code only get current page's selected item in listbox or datagridview.

foreach (string file in files) {
listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFullPath(file));
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(file);
int numberOfPages = pdfReader.NumberOfPages;
pdfPages.Text = pdfReader.NumberOfPages.ToString();
}

foreach (string dir in dirs){
listBox1.Items.Add((dir));
}

Comment: Are you trying to get the total number of pages of all the PDF files found in `files`?

Comment: No. im trying to get the total number of pages of all pdf file found/display in listBox.

Comment: Either I'm misunderstanding you, or you mean get the number of pages for the selected PDF in the list box. As it is right now, your question is worded towards getting the total number of pages of all the PDF files found in thr list box.

Comment: what i mean is like this. I have 13 pdf display in listbox each of them have 2 pages, in the textbox it will display total of 26 pages.
https://imgur.com/0q4py2Q.png

Comment: the code i posted is only get the pages of the selected file in the listbox.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For one, you are setting `numberOfPages` but then you aren't using it all.

If you are trying to get the total number of pages across all of the PDF files that `files` contains (as [your comment indicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73411590/get-total-pdf-pages-using-itextsharp-and-display-it-to-textbox?noredirect=1#comment129643426_73411590)), you should declare `numberOfPages` outside of the `foreach` and simply add to it within the `foreach`:

```cs
int numberOfPages = 0;
foreach (string file in files) 
{
   listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFullPath(file));
   PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(file);
   numberOfPages += pdfReader.NumberOfPages;
   pdfPages.Text = pdfReader.NumberOfPages.ToString();
}
```

You can then simply set the `Text` property of the textbox to `numberOfPages.ToString()`:

```cs
MyTextBox.Text = numberOfPages.ToString();
```

Comment: i tried this but same with my code it only gets selected pdf pages/